# How do I create a dictionary from two lists in python while maintaining all key value information?

Tags: python

### Example:

```
last_names = ['Bakir','Jose','Jose','Pierce']

university = ['Davis', 'Stanford', 'George Town', 'Berkeley']
```

#### Desire the Following

```
resulting_dictionary = {'Bakir':'Davis', 'Jose': ['Stanford', 'George Town'], 'Pierce':'Berkeley'}
```

#### I've tried the following

```
dictionary = {key:value for key, value in zip(last_names, university)}
```

But obtained the following:

```
{'Bakir': 'Davis', 'Jose': 'George Town', 'Pierce': 'Berkeley'}
```

Due to duplicate key value in last name list.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you really want nested lists, not `['Stanford', 'George Town']`?

Comment: I don’t see the point in a list of lists for Jose.  Wouldn’t `['Stanford', 'George Town']` suffice?

Comment: I agree, no need for nested lists for Jose. That was a fluke on my behalf.

Comment: @MBakir You should edit your question, not add requirements/clarifications as comments.

Answer (score 5):

Use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(last_names, university):
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dict.setdefault` method to initialize new keys with sub-lists:

```
dictionary = {}
for k, v in zip(last_names, university):
    dictionary.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value to a list, and check whether the key already exists and append to it.

```
dictionary = {}
for key, value in zip(last_names, university):
    if key in dictionary:
        dictionary[key].append(value)
    else:
        dictionary[key] = [value]
```

This will make all the values lists. It's generally easier if you're consistent about your data format, not mixing strings and lists. So the result will be:

```
{'Bakir':['Davis'], 'Jose': ['Stanford', 'George Town']], 'Pierce':['Berkeley']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as the question seems to imply, that a list is not desired if only one value is present for a key, a simple flattening post-step can be used to achieve the specified result.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(last_names, university):
   d[k].append(v)

# flatten single entry lists back to a string
d = { k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in d.items() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {}
for key, value in zip(last_names, university):
    if key in my_dict:
        old_value = my_dict[key]
        if isinstance (old_value, str):
            my_dict[key] = [old_value, value]
        else:
            old_value.add (value)
    else:
        my_dict[key] = value
```